# QSortFilterProxyModel and row numbers

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I'm using some tableview with related model extended with QSortFilterProxyModel because of sorting and/or filtering. Everything works fine except row numbers (I mean vertical header).
Using this code:

```
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.__header[section]
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return section + 1
```

fixed row number is assigned to each row. And this causes problems when sorting/filtering.
I figured out one solution: override default filtering and sorting methods and put some additional parameter (row number) into data and rewrite it during each sorting or filtering.

Question: is there any other solution for this? Some method which shows me real item position after sorting/filtering manipulation?

Comment: Do you really need those as headers? This would be much easier if you added another column in your model for 'row number'.

Comment: Yes, I prefer headers rather than cells because it looks more intuitive

Comment: Wait... I think I misunderstood. `QSortFilterProxyModel` actually keeps the original numbers intact. But you don't want that? You want the row number to go from `1` to `N` after sorting regardless of where the original row was, right?

Comment: yes, exactly - in the code snippet it's called with old indexes (section argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel` with custom `headerData` would do that:

```py
class MyProxy(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # if display role of vertical headers
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            # return the actual row number
            return section + 1
        # for other cases, rely on the base implementation
        return super(MyProxy, self).headerData(section, orientation, role)
```

Comment: No, not exactly - I'm focusing on vertical header which is the same as mine in your example.

Comment: @Miso: I'm going to repeat again. _This_ is `Proxy` model. This should go instead of `QSortFilterProxyModel`. I'm not suggesting this for your _actual_ model.

Comment: in other words, only way how to reach my goal is to reimplement sorting/filtering methods and setup new indexes variable, right?

Comment: @Miso: No, my answer is the _full_ implementation. You don't need anything extra. `MyProxy` just returns the vertical header based on the row of their sorted order, instead of asking it to the actual model (which was the reason for 'fixed' headers).

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast sending my previous comment. And yes, this is what I wanted! Thank you very much!